# Access multiple images from drawable folder

Tags: android, imageview

I want 100 images which are swipe left to right and right to left but and I don't want to write R.drawable.image_name 100 times so is there any solution to overcome this problem

```
public class SwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private int[]imageResource={R.drawable.nz,R.drawable.logo,R.drawable.i,R.drawable.ban};
```

Note: I'm using viewpager.

Comment: I would suggest to use a file renamer [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/file-renamer/9nblggh4rkqt?irgwc=1&OCID=AID681541_aff_7593_159229&tduid=%28ir__q3qlxnlydblvsb2ujn0xqp63we2xh2ugtf9edo1600%29%287593%29%28159229%29%28%29%28UUwpUdUnU56301%29&irclickid=_q3qlxnlydblvsb2ujn0xqp63we2xh2ugtf9edo1600&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) for example image_1 .... image_100 and you can populate it using a loop.

Comment: @ArbenMaloku Can't install this file as after signup this error generated( Where do you want to install?
It looks like you don’t have any applicable device(s) linked to your Microsoft account. To install, sign in on a device with your Microsoft account.

Get more info)